# How could i jump to function name more quickly?

Tags: vi

Is there some shortcut key or plugin to jump to function name more quickly in C++ or JAVA?

Often I used [[ or [{ , but it's also need some more motion to move the focus on function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are in C/C++ and your function's `{` has a single line.

you can create a new maping(should probably not override [[, chose something you like.):

```
nnoremap [[ [[kw
```

**EDIT:**

The final mapping which will work in most cases is:

```
nnoremap [f [[?(<cr>b
```

Comment: perhaps 1.my parameters list occupied two lines; 2. my function has more qualification, such as static. so [[kw sometimes doesn't work

Comment: Um.. I did not consider about multiply lines of parameters, but on the other hand, is tagbar or taglist ok for you?

Comment: In fact, I have these two plugin installed. I was wonder for some more quick means.

Comment: Then how about: `nnoremap [[ [[?(<cr>b` you probably wants to :noh in the second line:)

Comment: That works perfect for most cases, except some unusual format. nnoremap [f could be more better. 谢谢